# Accessing dockerized service (Rundeck) from a VM

Tags: docker, networking, ip, port, rundeck

Hello i have an Ubuntu VM (using bridged adapter) in which i'm running a docker container in which im starting Rundeck with a pre-build war file in a mounted Volume.When i run the war the first time it creates its files and the config file:

```
#loglevel.default is the default log level for jobs: 

ERROR,WARN,INFO,VERBOSE,DEBUG
loglevel.default=INFO
rdeck.base=/home/rundeck/rundeck

#rss.enabled if set to true enables RSS feeds that are public (non-authenticated)
rss.enabled=false
server.address=7d142a279564
grails.serverURL=http://7d142a279564:4440
dataSource.dbCreate = update
dataSource.url = jdbc:h2:file:/home/rundeck/rundeck/server/data/grailsdb;MVCC=true

# Pre Auth mode settings
rundeck.security.authorization.preauthenticated.enabled=false
rundeck.security.authorization.preauthenticated.attributeName=REMOTE_USER_GROUPS
rundeck.security.authorization.preauthenticated.delimiter=,
# Header from which to obtain user name
rundeck.security.authorization.preauthenticated.userNameHeader=X-Forwarded-Uuid
# Header from which to obtain list of roles
rundeck.security.authorization.preauthenticated.userRolesHeader=X-Forwarded-Roles
# Redirect to upstream logout url
rundeck.security.authorization.preauthenticated.redirectLogout=false
rundeck.security.authorization.preauthenticated.redirectUrl=/oauth2/sign_in

rundeck.log4j.config.file=/home/rundeck/rundeck/server/config/log4j.properties
```

As you see "server.address" and "grails.serverURL" get the default image ID as IP.
I can't access the container using this url,but i can access it using localhost:4440.But after loging in in rundeck it redirects me to "grails.serverURL" which gives "Server Not Found" as stated before.
This is how im starting the container:

```
sudo docker run -it -v /path/to/source:/path/to/dest -p 4440:4440  <imageID>
```

When i change the "server.address" and "grails.serverURL" to localhost or 127.0.0.1 i can't access the container at all.
Sorry if the question was answered before I'm new at docker and been at this for several days now,couldn't find a solution,Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert in rundeck, but looking at the [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/r/rundeck/rundeck) rundeck image has two env vars for setting the URL and address `RUNDECK_GRAILS_URL` and `RUNDECK_SERVER_ADDRESS`

`docker run -d -e RUNDECK_GRAILS_URL=http://127.0.0.1:4440 -e RUNDECK_SERVER_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0 -p 4440:4440 rundeck/rundeck`.

Now you can access your application at http://localhost:4440

In case if you're running your docker container in a remote server, then update your `RUNDECK_GRAILS_URL` as `RUNDECK_GRAILS_URL=http://<remote_server_ip>:4440`.

Now you can access your app at `http://remote_server_ip:4440`